# JavaScript if else is not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

```
function food(){
    var food_choice = document.getElementById('food-ch').value;
    console.log(food_choice);
    var food_arr = ['tuna','salmon','prawn','chicken'];
    for(key in food_arr){
        if(food_choice === food_arr[key]){
            console.log(food_arr[key]);
            $('#display-food').html("You have chosen "+food_arr[key]);
        }
        else{
            $('#display-food').html("Please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is not working as I intended to. Whenever I was entering one of the items from the array, it went to else part.

Comment: Instead of using `key in` you can just use `value of` so you don't need to access food_arr using key

Comment: Currently, the HTML assigned to `#display-food` will be the result of whatever is the very last iteration of the `for..in` loop.

Comment: Don't use `for..in` to iterate arrays. Also, you need to break the loop at first match.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem here is that you're iterating through the array of food but at every iteration that doesn't match, you're printing the "error" message so you never see that you've matched one of the values. Add a break statement on successful match

Comment: try the same code without === .  use == instead.

Comment: Don't use a loop at all. Use `food_arr.indexOf(food_choice)`

Comment: === just don't match the value it also matches the type and i think you need to match just the value

Comment: @prabhjot - The values are both the same type (strings).

Comment: Think very closely about your logic. Explain it to a rubber duck, or someone at the next desk. Write it on a blackboard and think through exactly what it is doing. Execute the code as if you were the computer, using a piece of paper. Walk through the code in a debugger, step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function food(){
     var food_choice = document.getElementById('food-ch').value;
     console.log(food_choice);
     var food_arr = ['tuna','salmon','prawn','chicken'];
     if(food_arr.indexOf(food_choice) != -1){
                $('#display-food').html("You have chosen" +food_choice);
    } else {
                $('#display-food').html("Please try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohan P. It is working. But could you please explain what was the problem in my code.

Comment: You need to check your selected item is exist or not, And you are checking from your array it is match or not with all elements. Surly it will not match with all element.